# /images Route not working in laravel web.php

Tags: laravel, routes

`Route::get("images", function (){ dd("route called successfully"); });`
I am trying to make a route in the web.php file like this:

But this is getting me 404 not found error.
Please help to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Please check your public folder, if you have folder called: `images`.
If yes, then your web route is directly calling your public folder's `images`  folder

To solve this, you need to rename your "images" folder's name.
OR make route with different name.

Comment: its working fine with your answer